# New opportunity button in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-platform

When I add New opportunity button to the lightning page, it shows up but only shows New opp...

Is it possible to make it show the whole word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. So this is the action bar I assume you are adding to. It's basically working with limited real estate and seems to limit you to around 6 characters (including whitespace) before it adds "..." when you are adding an Action to the lightning page or even a custom action to a standard layout (object or the global).

Some standard actions aren't affected by this and they have from what I've seen up to 8 (Question) characters available to display. But you'll see the standard New Opportunity has the same.

If you have 3 or more actions added and their text is long it will in fact hide all the text from the buttons. This is where logos come into use to teaching user behaviour based on memory instead of the title.

Comment: Thanks. How do you make it show image only instead of the label?

Comment: Since you can't add a zero width space and make label evaluate you need to have at least 3 actions added to the page after which it only displays the images. When you have more than 4 and you click on the action bar it shows you a list also showing the full name of each.

I'd actually recommend logging an idea on this as you should be able to specify the displayed characters in the actions in my opinion.